# All men are created equal - Why don't we say created EQUALLY?

Tags: grammaticality

This is a general English question. A friend asked me and I have no reason for it.
All men are created equal - Why don't we say created EQUALLY?

Comment: Because it’s the men (and women and everything in between) who are equal, not the way they’re created. Why do you think it should be ‘equally’?

Comment: I got your point but the line refers to human rights so whats wrong with saying all men were created equally

Comment: Consider the difference between 'Sir, you've marked my answer wrong!' and 'Sir, you've marked my answer wrongly!'

Comment: ... I trust you'd agree that 'He made me mad' is the correct choice, not 'He made me madly'. 'Mad' here is an adjectival resultative, describing _me_ after the encounter. / With 'He shot wide', it is arguable whether 'wide' should be construed as an adjective in a similar resultative construction (ie adding information about the resulting state), or as a flat adverb modifying _shoot_ (ie adding information about the action of shooting). / With your example, almost all people would say that here, the resultative (how men were the moment they appeared) is the focus, not the act of creation....

Comment: It is arguable, in fact, that 'All men are created equally' attempts to force a non-standard meaning on 'equally'. Neither of [AHDEL's listed senses](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/equally) <<
1. in an equal or identical manner: to treat rich and poor equally.
2. to an equal degree or extent. >> seems to license 'in such a way that they have equal rights'. 'Equal' has broadened in sense more than 'equally'.

Comment: Because it's a quote from the US Declaration of Independence, and that's the way Thomas Jefferson wrote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the adjective EQUAL, you are referring to the attributes or features of all men, but, with the adverb EQUALLY emphasis is placed on the CREATOR.  The adverb EQUALLY in ALL MEN (ARE) CREATED EQUALLY modifies the verb CREATED while the adjective EQUAL in ALL MEN ARE CREATED EQUAL qualifies the noun MEN. 
Also, I think using the word EQUAL will force the verb to be PRESENT...we **are** created EQUAL not we **were** created equal and the use of EQUALLY will make the verb past...We **were** created EQUALLY not we **are** created EQUALLY...the creation took place sometime ago but our qualifies are not stale or past.

Answer (score 2):

1. Graceful

   - All women are created graceful, by Allah. Allah created women to be graceful.
   - All women are created gracefully by Allah. Allah gracefully created women. If not for Allah's graceful consideration, all heterosexual men would have been terribly lonely.
2. Innocent

   - All the accused are declared innocent, by the judge today.
   - All the accused are declared innocently, by the judge today. The accused are declared by the judge today, and the judge is doing it innocently and naively.
3. Equal

   - All the goats were cloned equal, by engineering. Every goat looked and behaved similarly. They all had the same susceptibility and defence reaction to each disease vector and bacterial exposure.
   - All the goats were cloned equally, by engineering. The engineer had equally cloned the goats. Each clone was given the same meticulous care, the same cautious preparation, under the same temperature and ambient conditions. Engineering ensured there was as little variability as possible in every conceivable parameter. Surprise, surprise - the goats did not grow up to be equal.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was downvoted. It seems perfectly correct and clear to me. I've voted it back up.